# Roofing question: main stack sealing

Tags: waterproofing, roofing

[image]Main stack is 3" ABS inside the house replacing the original cast iron.  At the top, the cast iron going through the roof was left in place for convenience and the ABS was run through it.  The roof at that point is flat and is torch-on/torch-down.  The roof leaks at this point every couple of years and causes internal damage. There was no boot installed there and just a piece of torch-down around the cast iron stack.  My suspicion is that the cast iron gets very hot in summer time and expands and contracts, creating the cracks through which standing water leaks through in winter.  My question is: should I get a boot installed on the cast iron vent, or, have the cast iron removed (it is accessible inside the attic space) and then a boot installed on the ABS?

Comment: A picture would really be great.

Comment: Too wet to get up there today!